# Show a <div> once every hour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a `<div>` element once per hour, but the code is not working, when I add the following:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='showOnceAnHour' style='display: none'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#showOnceAnHour").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
    }, 60*60*1000);
});
</script>
```

This code is working fine without it but I want to show that content once per hour. Please take a look and let me know where I am going wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

.btnadpop {
    background: #428bca;
    border: #357ebd solid 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    transition: color .1s ease;
}
.btnadpop:hover {
    background: #357ebd;
}
.btnadpop.btn-big {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.btn-close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
.btn-close:hover {
    color: #919191;
}
.modaladpop:target:before {
    display: none;
}
.modaladpop:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.modaladpop .modal-dialoger {
    background: #fefefe;
    border: #333333 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 360px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    top: 20%;
}
.modaladpop:target .modal-dialoger {
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
    transform: translate(0, -500%);
}
.modal-bodyadpop {
    padding: 20px;
}
.modal-headeradpop, .modal-footer {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modal-headeradpop {
    border-bottom: #eeeeee solid 1px;
}
.modal-headeradpop h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.modal-footeradpop {
    border-top: #eeeeee solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='showOnceAnHour' style='display: none'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#showOnceAnHour").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
    }, 60*60*1000);
});
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modaladpop" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialoger">
        <div class="modal-headeradpop">
             <h2>Welcome</h2>
 

        </div>
        <div class="modal-bodyadpop">
            <p>This is an Example</p>
        </div>
        <div id="butnclose" class="modal-footeradpop"> <a href="#modal-one" class="btnadpop">Close</a>
        <script>
        document.getElementById("butnclose").style.display = "none";

        function showStuff() {
            document.getElementById("butnclose").style.display = "block";
        }


        setTimeout(showStuff, 5000);
    
</script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847412/how-to-call-a-function-every-hour)

Comment: Jquery is not imported in the snippet you attached with this question. This probably the issue in your code too

Comment: What is the error you see in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use jQuery selectors but you are not importing the jQuery library, you can do so by adding this in your HTML head:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This is not JavaScript, this is just a script import you need to put in your `<head>` somewhere, and then your code should work fine. Here is your file with the import added: https://gist.github.com/b023a2fa80d0515942534f0f3c5a6a22

Comment: Thanks that worked, But it shows after one hour and not on the first time, is there any way to show it first time on page load and then after once every hour

Comment: Sure, just add `$("#showOnceAnHour").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();` after line 127, this will just fade it in once and show it for 10 seconds, and then hide it again for the next hour.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got what I wanted, thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

You are just missing JQuery CDN or static import in your code.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='showOnceAnHour' style='display: none'><h1>Div</h1></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#showOnceAnHour").fadeIn().delay(10).fadeOut();
    }, 60);
});
</script>



<h3>I Just changes the fadeIn and fadeOut time for demo purpose</h3>
```